# How programatically activate data frame in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, arcgis-10.3

I want to:

1. create new data frame,
2. give it a name,
3. activate it and then fill with layers, etc. in ArcMap .NET custom command.

With this code I achieve 1. and 2., but don't know how to activate it:

```c#
// mxDocument is IMxDocument
IMap newMap = mxDocument.Maps.Create();
newMap.Name = "I can name it as I want: " + Guid.NewGuid();
mxDocument.Maps.Add(newMap);
//HOW TO Activate newMap???
mxDocument.UpdateContents();
```

New data frame is created, added to TOC but how to make it active?

```c#
mxDocument.ActiveView.FocusMap = newMap
```

gives System.NotImplementedException.

EDIT: IMaps.Create() +  IMaps.Add() is too primitive way to create a data frame, it won't work properly. See this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134298/how-to-properly-initialize-arcmap-data-frame-created-with-imaps-create-method/134315) for a better description.

Comment: Is this question really supposed to have the Python tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting ActiveView (rather than FocusMap) to newMap:

```c#
mxDocument.ActiveView = newMap
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked (with a cast): mxDocument.ActiveView = (IActiveView)newMap.