# How to properly initialize ArcMap data frame created with IMaps.Create method?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, arcgis-10.2

In a custom ArcMap command implemented in .NET C# I create a new data frame this way:

```
// mxDocument is IMxDocument
IMap newMap = mxDocument.Maps.Create(); // create new data frame
newMap.Name = "I can name it as I want: " + Guid.NewGuid();
mxDocument.Maps.Add(newMap);
mxDocument.ActiveView = (IActiveView)newMap; // activate new data frame
mxDocument.UpdateContents();
```

However, compared to the data frame created with standard ArcMap means, there is something wrong with my data frame:

1. ArcMap doesn't show property page for the data frame (right click -
   Properties)
2. It's not possible to remove my data frame from ArcMap
   (right click - Remove)

Do I have to add some initialization code for IMap created with IMaps.Create (IMaps2.Create)?

The help for the method is quite laconic: "Creates a new map"...

I use ArcGIS version 10.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet should add a new dataframe:

```
IApplication app = default(IApplication);
IMxDocument pMxDoc = default(IMxDocument);

app = (IApplication)Hook;
pMxDoc = (IMxDocument)My.ArcMap.Application.Document;

//Create a new map
IMap pMap = default(IMap);
pMap = new Map();
pMap.Name = "My Map2";

//Create a new MapFrame and associate map with it
IMapFrame pMapFrame = default(IMapFrame);
pMapFrame = new MapFrame();
pMapFrame.Map = pMap;

//Set the position of the new map frame
IElement pElement = default(IElement);
IEnvelope pEnv = default(IEnvelope);
pElement = pMapFrame;
pEnv = new Envelope();
pEnv.PutCoords(0, 0, 5, 5);
pElement.Geometry = pEnv;

//Add mapframe to the layout
IGraphicsContainer pGraphicsContainer = default(IGraphicsContainer);
pGraphicsContainer = pMxDoc.PageLayout;
pGraphicsContainer.AddElement(pMapFrame, 0);

//Make the newly added map the focus map
IActiveView pActiveView = default(IActiveView);
pActiveView = pMxDoc.ActiveView;
if (pActiveView is IPageLayout) {
    pActiveView.FocusMap = pMap;
} else {
    pMxDoc.ActiveView = pMap;
}

//Refresh ActiveView and TOC
pActiveView.Refresh();
pMxDoc.CurrentContentsView.Refresh(0);
```

Sourced from [How to create a new map](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000082000000)